# Filter away INT_MIN when doing DSP since -INT_MIN is undefined(?)

Tags: transfer-function, self-study, quantization

My problem is that I have a mic that delivers 24 bits 2's complement signed. There is nothing in that data sheet that hints at it not also delivering `INT_MIN`. The 8 LSB bits are zero and `INT_MIN` is `0x80000000`. I have myself written the driver, which takes in bits for stereo (needed even if I only use one mic) at an SCK rate of exactly 1024 kHz for 16 kHz samples. Only one of the stereo channels are valid.

`INT_MIN` could potentially be a problem. I am making a mask of `abs` of all the signed values, for a 32 ms window and not sending those into the FFT etc. That mask would then get `NumLeadingZeros` completely wrong if `INT_MIN` is only one sample. The AGC (before the FFT) would fail miserably.

From the fist version of this question (which was about to be shipped to Stack Overflow) I was advised that "it's almost always better to insure that `x = - INT_MIN` equals `INT_MAX`". So I assume that this probably is about as good answer as I could expect.

1. Instead of doing the `absx` as described below I have now made a function that does exactly what suggested above
2. When it comes to the FFT, I don't know if `INT_MIN` would be a problem. I could analyse the source, but it's a library in assembly code. I haven't tested `INT_MIN`, since analysing the result would be difficult for me. On a general basis, standard FFT (with `int32_t` input), might `INT_MIN` be a problem?

I'll keep the original text below, even if it may misled the reader to think that I was concerned with the `abs` vs. `absx`. Partly because many of the responses relate to it.

--- From original posting:

In [Why the absolute value of the max negative integer -2147483648 is still -2147483648?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243014/why-the-absolute-value-of-the-max-negative-integer-2147483648-is-still-2147483) we see that since 2's complement is not symmetrical (it can't be, because zero also needs a space) I have come to *not* "believe" in my old `abs` macro (C). The problem is `INT_MIN`, which is on a one value "longer" negative "ruler" than the positive "ruler", which ends at "one shorter" value `INT_MAX`.

So `abs(INT_MIN)` strictly is not defined.

Per def `abs(any_signed_value)` should yield a positive value in my head. The math after this could really misbehave if not so. My standard macro does not deliver as I want to:

`#define abs(a) (((a)<0)?(-(a)):(a))`

But this one takes the last value that it's possible to invert when it sees `INT_MIN`, namely `INT_MAX`:

`#define absx(a) ((a)==(INT_MIN)?(INT_MAX):((a)<0)?(-(a)):(a))`

Testing with this code (xC on XMOS X2 core) I get:

```
#include <limits.h>
void test_abs (void) {  
    signed int_min    = INT_MIN;
    signed int_min_p1 = INT_MIN + 1;

    debug_print ("abs(int_min)\t%d - abs(int_min_p1)\t%d\n",    abs(int_min),  abs(int_min_p1));
    debug_print ("absx(int_min)\t%d - absx(int_min_p1)\t%d\n", absx(int_min), absx(int_min_p1));

    // abs(int_min) -2147483648 - abs(int_min_p1)  2147483647
    // absx(int_min) 2147483647 - absx(int_min_p1) 2147483647

    signed int_zero = 0;
    signed int_pos  = 1;

    debug_print ("abs(int_zero)\t%d - abs(int_pos)\t%d\n",    abs(int_zero),  abs(int_pos));
    debug_print ("absx(int_zero)\t%d - absx(int_pos)\t%d\n", absx(int_zero), absx(int_pos));

    // abs(int_zero)  0 - abs(int_pos)  1
    // absx(int_zero) 0 - absx(int_pos) 1
}
```

I don't want an assert for the `INT_MIN` case, I instead want to keep on running.

Would anybody see some side effect of this that I don't see? Wikipedia [Absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) doesn't make it simpler, does it.

Comment: While this question has bearing on signal processing (for a given variable `x` it's almost always better to insure that `x = - INT_MIN` equals `INT_MAX`), it's really a question about C and the C standard.  There's already a lot of material about this on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com), and if you ask 'why' the conversation quickly gets into the minutia of the C standard -- which is outside the purview of this group.

Comment: If I was to give a general recommendation about writing C for DSP, it would be that *macros are basically never a good idea*. You want to have a *function* $f(x) = \lvert y\rvert$, so write a *function* `int abs(int value);`; for good measure, you can slap an `inline` in front of that, but you win absolutely nothing by writing this as a macro, unless your compiler is older than it should be or running with any kind of code restructuring disabled (and then you wouldn't want a macro, either). You can also simply use your compiler to verify a function is correct: enable optimizations, and just

Comment: loop over the whole integer range! Look at https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3MKMbojvc : my `inline int abs(int)` gets completely compiled away, because it's never different from the correct value, so the `assert` never triggers, so there's not actually any code to execute. The compiler knows this, because it does understand that `abs(int value)` does in fact compute `value` for `value >=0` and `-value` for anything else but `INT_MIN`. Easy-peasy for the code analyzer to just erase a `-value == -value` check, and even easier for it to remove `value == value`. You really win nothing with macros!

Comment: Thanks! I never really found out what to use where. I used an inline function the other day for wrapping around an asm. I see that the lib_dsp and others would use macros (in C) a lot, like for "Convert from floating point to fixed point Q format like #define Q31(f) (int)((signed long long)((f) * ((unsigned long long)1 << (31+20)) + (1<<19)) >> 20)". But I take your point. But from my test code it looks like the compiler (llvm based, 2019 ca: xccllvm) does val=(-INT_MIN) as no change, which is "legal" from the standard it looks like, (..)

Comment: (..) but I'll have to interfere. I'll keep that in mind and try to move away from macros! I also take the point to clean my dataset from INT_MIN initially to avoid this specialised absx. I also read that doing what I suggest is "ok enough". Thanks!

Comment: @MarcusMuller did you mean that the test in godbolt in main should be _verified_ by the compiler, and no run-time would be made? It looks like there is some run-time in main, but not much looping. Mine looped, loops and still loops on the board.

Comment: @ØyvindTeig When in doubt, you can ask if a topic is suitable in dsp.meta.stackexchange.com. I'd encourage you to re-frame your question and post again.

Comment: By the way, the test at godbolt took about 150 seconds on the XMOS xCORE X2 running alone on one "logical core" (of 8 on the tile, 16 on the chip) (500 MHz / 8 = 62.5 MHz per core), so 150s / 2exp32 = 0,03492459654808 us = 35 ns / loop. Quite ok for a microcontroller that won't even melt butter:-)